# Why is a ground wire required between main and subpanels?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I am trying to get a understanding as to WHY some people say this is wrong.

The setup I have is main panel is 200 amp in a chicken house. I want to install a 100 amp subpanel in a new garage that is 80' away.

The 200 amp main panel would get a 100 amp breaker, then that would feed into the subpanel with a 100 amp main breaker with 2/2/4 aluminum wiring (4 being the neutral). The subpanel would have 2 ground rods 8' apart, one for CB panel bonding, one for ground rail.

How is this inferior to running a 2/2/4/6 and connecting the ground to the main panel that goes to a ground rod?

I do not understand the point of running a 4th wire 80' when I can ground it at the source.

Comment: This question should help explain it.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/163680/three-wire-vs-four-wire-feed-remote-sub-panel?rq=1     100 amp breaker might be too much for that wire.  2/2/ is usually limited to 90 amps.

Comment: Why it's wrong is because current code requires a ground from a main panel to a sub panel. Are you asking why current code requires that?

Comment: Is your farm built on a giant copper nugget? If not, how do you expect dirt to conduct as well?  So with the dirt being practically useless for clearing faults, you have this problem.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE  Also, 2-2-4 is still only 90A feeder unless we are dealing with overhead.  Different rules for that.  And undersizing neutral is generally not allowed in residential, or in commercial without a load study validating it.